# How to Return Result of AWS Lambda Function to Android App?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a web page where I can perform CRUD operations on a DynamoDB. This web page is written in PHP and works perfectly for performing operations on the database.

I also have a Lambda function that polls the stream every time any operation is performed through this website. It polls the stream, gets all the records and returns the data as a String.

Both the web page to update the DB and the Lambda function are working as intended. However, I also have an android app that relies on data in the DB for various things. My question is how could I access the String returned by the DynamoDB from my android app? Basically, I want the lambda function to run every time the database is updated through the web page (this is done) and then automatically return the String of updated records directly to the android app. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement Google's [Firebase Cloud Messaging API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). It is fast, well integrated into Android (and many other platforms), reliable, and you get a ton of [free](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) features out of the box. You can look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/#key_capabilities) for a quick feature overview to see if it is right for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, went with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the above requirement correctly, you need to send notification to android application. I think this can be achieved using AWS SNS. It has the feature to send the notification to mobile device.

> Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) is a flexible, fully managed
>   pub/sub messaging and mobile notifications service for coordinating
>   the delivery of messages to subscribing endpoints and clients. With
>   SNS you can fan-out messages to a large number of subscribers,
>   including distributed systems and services, and mobile devices.
>
> Amazon SNS Mobile Notifications makes it simple and cost effective to
>   send push notifications to iOS, Android, Fire OS, Windows and
>   Baidu-based devices.

Refer this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) for SNS Mobile Push